# how to set parent scrollable when children is added dinamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

click on the button several times

why `.wrap - max-height` doesn't work

I'm expecting it to be limited by `100vh - 108px` and also `.ins` to be scrollable if needed.

Any help?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let a = "<div class='abc'>ABC</div>";
  $(a).appendTo($('#ins'));
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  position:fixed;
 left:50%;
 top:54px;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
 max-height:calc(100vh - 108px);
  background:silver;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.title{background:gold;}
.bottom{margin-top:5px;}
.sub{background:orange;}
.ins{overflow-y:scroll;}
.abc{background:lightgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='title'>LOREM</div>
<div class='bottom'>
<div class='sub'>IPSUM</div>
<div class='ins' id='ins'>
<div class='abc'>ABC</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` after `silver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change .ins to like this below

```js
    $('button').on('click', function(){
    let a = "<div class='abc'>ABC</div>";
    $(a).appendTo($('#ins'));
  });
```

```css
.wrap{
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:54px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  max-height:calc(100vh - 108px);
  background:silver;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.ins {
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: calc(100vh - 108px);
}
.title{background:gold;}
.bottom{margin-top:5px;}
.sub{background:orange;}
.abc{background:lightgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button>CLICK</button>
    <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='title'>LOREM</div>
    <div class='bottom'>
    <div class='sub'>IPSUM</div>
    <div class='ins' id='ins'>
    <div class='abc'>ABC</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it works but bottm arrow on scrollbar is not visible

Comment: @qadenza wait let me check and fix it for you

Comment: just use it in your project it just behaving here snippet .. you dont wory it will work in your project if not then increase 108  to someting greater .. let me know if still have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the .wrap properties like below and add `min-width`

```
.wrap{
  position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:54px;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    max-height:calc(100vh - 108px);
  background:silver
  overflow:auto;
  min-height: 300px /* or whatsoever you want to make the height of container stable when minimum content is there */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works well after add the missing ";" here:

background:silver;

also, scroll needs height.. so add add height for it to work.